# Making Pyramid application without session timeout

Tags: python, apache, session, mod-wsgi, pyramid

I am making a pyramid webapp running in apache webserver using mod_wsgi. Is there anyway I could make user session never timed out? (The idea is so that once user logged in, the system will never kicked them out unless they logged out themselves). I cant find any information regarding this in apache, mod_wsgi or pyramid documentation. Thanks!

Comment: I'm trying to search the documentation, too. For my own pyramid projects, the default login session (as modeled on the "wiki" tutorial) does seem to never timeout unless I restart the application.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In my case, some user do have long session timeout, but some experienced sudden kickout from the system. Do you have any idea why this could happen?

Answer (score 0):

This entirely depends on the authentication policy that you use. The default `AuthTktAuthenticationPolicy` sets a cookie in the browser which (by default) does not expire. Again though, this depends on how you are tracking authenticated users.